# append method not work in class method for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
class modify:
def __init__(self, a):
    bogota = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
    bogota.append(a, ignore_index=True)
    print(bogota.tail(2))
modify(inputt)
```

here **inputt** is series object.

In Output, I not get appended dataframe. **append** work outside the class but in class method append method not working how to resolve this?

Comment: this works exactly the same inside a method or outside of it

Comment: For interest why do you have a class here? Seems that `def modify(a):` will be a better idea.

Comment: your indentation is not correct, is that the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

"Append rows of other to the end of caller, returning a new object."

You must assign the output to a new variable to store the appended result. Append does not mutate the original `bogota` dataframe.

```
new_var = bogota.append(a, ignore_index=True)
print(new_var.tail(2))
```